# Complex aggregation after group by operation in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this DataFrame in pandas that I have that I've grouped by a column.

After this operation I need to generate all unique pairs between the rows of 
each group and perform some aggregate operation on all the pairs of a group.

I've implemented the following sample algorithm to give you an idea. I want to refactor this code in order to make it work with pandas to yield performance increase and/or decrease code complexity.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

#Construct Dataframe
samples=40
a=np.random.randint(3,size=(1,samples))
b=np.random.randint(9,size=(1,samples))
c=np.random.randn(1,samples)
d=np.append(a,b,axis=0)
e=np.append(d,c,axis=0)
e=e.transpose()
df = pd.DataFrame(e,columns=['attr1','attr2','value'])
df['attr1'] = df.attr1.astype('int')
df['attr2'] = df.attr2.astype('int')

#drop duplicate rows so (attr1,attr2) will be key
df = df.drop_duplicates(['attr1','attr2'])
#df = df.reset_index()
print(df)


for key,tup in df.groupby('attr1'):

    print('Group',key,' length ',len(tup))
    #generate pairs
    agg=[]
    for v1,v2 in itertools.combinations(list(tup['attr2']),2):
        p1_val = float(df.loc[(df['attr1']==key) & (df['attr2']==v1)]['value'])
        p2_val = float(df.loc[(df['attr1']==key) & (df['attr2']==v2)]['value'])
        agg.append([key,(v1,v2),(p1_val-p2_val)**2])

    #insert pairs to dataframe
    p = pd.DataFrame(agg,columns=['group','pair','value'])
    top = p.sort_values(by='value').head(4)
    print(top['pair'])
    #Perform some operation in df based on pair values
    #....
```

I am really afraid that pandas DataFrames can not provide such sophisticated analysis functionality.

Do I have to stick to traditional python like in the example?

I'm new to Pandas so any comments/suggestions are welcome.